# How to make a .s3d depth map for video?

Tags: 3d, video, depth

Is there any software that is able to make a depth map for a video and export it to .s3d format?

[image]

Similar to this photo but I need to make a video.

I found this one but not sure which suite of the apps is suitable
http://www.yuvsoft.com/

Comment: Why do not you mail them and ask them?

Answer (score 1):

I can not give you any tutorial because it is a little complex.

This is a function that you can google using this terms:

cloud+point+3d+from+video

https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+point+3d+from+vide

Some aplications have it, even blender. So add the term "blender"

https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+point+3d+from+video+blender

So you will get a 3D point cloud.

Then you need to convert it into a mesh and using the calculated camera position you could generate a render using that data.

The tools you linked gives you a shortcut to that process.

---

Edited.

The previows text is an alternative method.

Here is a free software. I have not tested it yet. http://3dstereophoto.blogspot.mx/p/software.html

http://3dstereophoto.blogspot.mx/2015/06/depth-map-automatic-generator-8-dmag8.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but I tried to search with your keywords, then I don't get the depth map result. I guess it is nothing to to do with 3d rendering, it is a type of stereo 2d to 3d conversion using depth map. My problem is i don't know which software can output the video with left side is normal color and right side is black and white channel for 3D definition.

Comment: Here is the example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD3W8JKGC8k

Comment: A depth map is used in 3D rendering. The point here is how to extract the 3D data. That is using point cloud data.